# How to extend command stored in sh variable with parameters?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I tried to google the problem and play with different approaches but I failed to actually execute the command :/ I want to construct a command in a set of conditional checks. Here is what I want to achieve:

```sh
run_script=`command`

if type command &>/dev/null; then
    run_script=`command`
else
    run_script=`something command`
fi

# while ... do
    $params=`-a -b -c` # calculated
    $anotherparam = "./test.file" # calculated

    # run $run_script+$params+$anotherparam ???
    # like we run "command -a -b -c ./test.file" command
# done
```

*Note: it's just an example*

How can I do this type of combination? I can's use arrays because I need it to be compatible with sh

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will raise strong opinions.

**If you are completely sure that you will only receive trusted, non-malicious input, `eval` is part of the standard shell and a perfect tool for this task.**

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278427/why-and-when-should-eval-use-be-avoided-in-shell-scripts

> The arguments are concatenated together into a single command, which
>   is then read and executed, and its exit status returned as the exit
>   status of eval. If there are no arguments or only empty arguments, the
>   return status is zero.

```
if type command &>/dev/null; then
    run_script="command"
else
    run_script="something command"
fi

params="-a -b -c" # calculated
anotherparam="./test.file" # calculated

eval "$run_script $params $anotherparam"
```

Comment: I tried it but I get these errors:
`eval: line 1: ______: not found`, `eval: line 2: /: Permission denied`, `eval: line 68: syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution`. The command itself can not generate permission errors because it performs ok if I just run it by myself (without root and access)

Comment: For example this simple one: `run_script=\`ls\`;eval "echo $run_script -a .";`. It generates error on each listed file: `eval: line 1: FILE_NAME: not found` and so on.

Comment: you don't have to use execution quoutes. For this example you need: `run_script="ls";eval "$run_script -a ."`

Comment: Please do not advertise the use of eval, it is terrible and dangerous.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278427/why-and-when-should-eval-use-be-avoided-in-shell-scripts

Answer (score 3):

Correct POSIX sh way of dynamically constructing a command call with parameters:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

run_script='command'

if command -v "$run_script" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    set -- "$run_script"
else
    set -- "something" "$run_script"
fi

# while ... do
#    $params=`-a -b -c` # calculated
    set -- "$@" -a -b -c # calculated
#    $anotherparam = "./test.file" # calculated
    set -- "$@" "./test.file" # calculated
    # run $run_script+$params+$anotherparam ???
    "$@" # run command with its parameters
    # like we run "command -a -b -c ./test.file" command
# done
```

Explanations:

- `if command -v "$run_script" >/dev/null 2>&1`: Tests if the `"$run_script"` command exists.
- `set -- "$run_script"`: Sets the arguments array to the `"$run_script"` command.
- `set -- "something" "$run_script"`: Sets the arguments array to the `something` command with first argument `"$run_script"`.
- `set -- "$@" -a -b -c`: Sets the arguments array with `"$@"` current content of the arguments array, and `-a`, `-b` and `-c` as additional arguments.
- Stand-alone `"$@"`: Calls the command and arguments contained in the arguments array.

Comment: What about @sergio's answer? I guess it's almost the same as `eval`.

Comment: I understand why `eval` could be considered bad practice, but the script I'm building has no user interaction and for internal use only and all the parameters are strictly pre-defined. I'm not that familiar with shell scripting and POSIX and only use it for small automation routines, but your example seems a bit over-engineered and verbose, what are the benefits (except for user-input injection problems)?

Comment: @Stanislav I can't get how it is "over-engineered and verbose" to use `set -- parameters`, it has the same number of statements as your submission, it does exactly what you asked for, the right and portable way. If the term `POSIX` sounds too rough to you, feel free to use a Bash array instead of the `$@` array, but it will not reduce verbosity or enhance readability.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```sh
if type -p command; then
    run_script="command"
else
    run_script="something command"
fi

params="-a -b -c"
anotherparam="./test.file"

"$run_script" $params $anotherparam
```

Changes to OP code:

- use `type -p cmd` instead of `type cmd &>/dev/null`
- use quotes instead of backticks for `run_script="command"`
- remove spaces around the equal sign `=`
- remove `$` from left side of the equal sign

Comment: It works without quotes too. Relating suggested changes to my op code - I wrote it in web editor only for the explanation of my task, I know the syntax in commented while is not correct :)